# How can I make this code with all the loops more elegant?

Tags: c, for-loop, nested-loops

I am grinding away at a simple for-loop exercise where the user can enter a width and a height, and the program prints out a square with stars and spaces, like this:

```
Enter width and height: 8 4

********
*      *
*      *
********
```

and I have made a solution, but it just feels like I could redsuce the number of blocks with loops some... Can somebody help me with this? Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int width, height;

    printf("Enter width and height: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &width, &height);

    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < height - 2; i++)
    {
        printf("*");
        for (int j = 0; j < width -2; j++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("*\n");
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }      
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "I could nest the loops even more" maybe, do you have a special reason to try? What would be the verification to check whether a given solution is correct?

Comment: Now if you would ask for "more elegant" instead of "more nested", there are possibilities. Or maybe "more fancy", or "more impressively convoluted", or "more hard too read". There would also be a way to do it with only a single loop in total...

Comment: If you really insist on more nesting, simply add a few more layers of that useless `for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)` you already used. With different counter variables of course. That way you can have as many unneeded nesting levels as you like.

Comment: For fun try this line: `printf("*%*s*\n", width-2, "");`

Comment: And if you can accept a maximum for `width` you can also try:    `printf("%.*s\n", width, "********************************");`

Comment: Is this a "language" thing? Any sane person would ask, "How can I **reduce** the nesting in this code?"

Comment: @Yunnosch I am just trying to become better at this. this is a school assignment, I know I'll pass it as it is, but it would be nice if I would actually learn something more while doing it.. I guess I meant more elegant then :) just exercising the brain :)

Comment: @SupportUkraine I have that line to print out the top and the bottom lines of stars..

cool, thing, with that line. haven't tried it, but I see where it is going :)

Comment: @DimitriMikhalev Just delete it... and see whether your program behaves differently ;-)

Comment: "I am just trying to become better at this." In that case my advice is "do less nesting", at least get rid of the useless outer loops which only iterate once. Me as your teacher, I'd dock some points off your score for those.

Comment: @Fe203 hahaha ... I guess I meant that... hmm.. currently I am repeating the same process for the top and bottom lines, I guess that I wanted to know if I could have those in the same loop instead of the same loop but in two different places

Comment: I think it is time to [edit] the question post in order to ask the question you actually mean. Be careful to not contradict the existing answer (which I  however think happens to answer the question you mean instead of the one you asked, so you are probably fine).

Comment: @Yunnosch I edited it now for better clarity

Comment: Nice edit, thanks. (Oh look! No close-vote for lack of clarity anymore. ;-)  )

Comment: Just read your comment _almost_ addressed to me. (That's 'F', 'e', '2' 'Oh' '3'... not "203".) To answer your question, yes... Reusing code by extracting it into a function (that can be called from separate locations) is a _GOOD_ thing to try to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way could be:

```
int main(void)
{
    int width = 8;
    int height = 4;
    for (int h = 0; h < height; ++h)
    {
        for (int w = 0; w < width; ++w)
        {
            if (w == 0 || h == 0 || h == (height-1) || w == (width-1))
            {
                putchar('*');
            }
            else
            {
                putchar(' ');
            }
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

That said... IMO this isn't really better than your approach. The use of 3 simple "loop-blocks" makes it very easy to see what your code is doing. This approach with a single "loop-block" and an `if` statement is a bit harder to read.

So I would say...

You approach/code is fine if you just delete the lines

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
```

as they do absolutely nothing.

And use `putchar` instead of `printf` for printing a single character.

Then your approach is pretty okay. If you want to avoid the first and last loop-block to be the same (i.e. avoid repeating the same code), you could put the code into a function.

Answer (score 2):

I packaged some loop lines into function. Here is the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
void PrintCharLine(char c, int width){
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++){
        putchar(c);
    }
}
void PrintEdge(int width){
    PrintCharLine('*', width);
    printf("\n");
}
void PrintBody(int width, int height){
    for(int i = 0; i < height - 2; i++)
    {
        printf("*");
        PrintCharLine(' ', width -2);
        printf("*\n");
    }
}
int main(void)
{
    int width, height;
    printf("Enter width and height: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &width, &height);

    PrintEdge(width);
    PrintBody(width, height);
    PrintEdge(width);
}
```

as @Support Ukraine said, you can replace PrintCharLine with printf("%.*s for less for loop. but the width range has some limit.

Comment: @caveman1314 thx for the most advanced answer haha :D

Comment: Nitpick: `printf("\n");` --> `putchar('\n');`  (all places where a single char is printed)

Comment: I would probably even turn `printf("*\n");` into 2 `putchar` or at least use `puts("*");` instead

Answer (score 0):

Here's another variation. Factor out "common" code into a "helper function"

```
#include <stdio.h>

void row( int wid, int fill ) {
    wid -= 2;
    putchar( '*' );
    while( wid-- )
        putchar( fill ? '*' : ' ' );
    putchar( '*' );
    putchar( '\n' );
}

int main() {
    int width, height;

    printf( "Enter width and height: " );
    if( scanf( "%d%d", &width, &height ) != 2 ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "scanf() failure\n" );
        return 1;
    }

    row( width, 1 );
    for( int i = 1; i < height - 1; i++ )
        row( width, 0 );
    row( width, 1 );

    return 0;
}
```

And when you've done that, you begin to notice even more economies that make a "helper function" so trivial its code is returned to the calling location...

```
int main() {
    int width, height;

    printf( "Enter width and height: " );
    if( scanf( "%d%d", &width, &height ) != 2 ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "scanf() failure\n" );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < height; i++ ) {
        int wid = width - 2;
        int fill =
#ifdef PEDESTRIAN
            (i == 0 || i == height-1) ? '*' : ' ';
#else
            " *"[!(i%(height-1))];
#endif
        putchar( '*' );
        while( wid-- ) putchar( fill );
        puts( "*" );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: IMO it's not a good idea to make simple stuff complicated. Shorter but more complex code should never be a goal.

Comment: @SupportUkraine Of course, you are entitled to have your view... Showing the beginner alternatives, though, is not a bad idea, is it? Look at the "final" version in this answer. A `for()` loop for each line, a bunch of `putchar()` calls, and some **wizardry** to determine if the "fill" character is a SP or "*"... Less chance of (as has been an SO question) copy/paste with `for( i = 0 ... j++)`... Almost invisible!! especially in a morass of code. Let's agree to disagree... `:-)`

Comment: yes, let's disagree. If someone was shown the code in your last example, it would take them quite some time to figure out what the code is doing. That's a bad sign, IMO

Comment: @SupportUkraine While I admit the selection of the fill char is "too clever" (could be broken out into a series of statements), There is, imho, _nothing_ challenging about this code... It gets two values, reduces width by 2 (frame L&R), then loops for the number of rows desired, calling `putchar()` a bunch of times... Please explain what would require "quite some time" to understand? (Yes, the _wizardry_ selecting a character is obscure, but it works, and, when understood, is an idiom acquired by the reader... Always learning... `:-)` (PS: Uncommented code here. Mea culpa...)